# Should I add page level compression before adding the primary key, or after?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

### Situation

- Data warehouse on Sql Server 2008 Enterprise
- 36+ million row heap (don't ask), with 60+ columns
- 750k added monthly
- No primary key defined (I have now identified one)
- No compression

### What I'm thinking of doing (in this order)

- Add page level compression
- Add the PK
- Add a number of non-clustered indexes
- Do this as quickly as possible

### Question

- **Ultimately: Do I add the PK or the page compression first? (Does it matter?)**
- If I add the compression first to the table, will any indexes then *inherit* the table level compression settings? [The answer to this particular question is "No, compression is not inherited", found here on dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/28034/7226)

### What I'm leaning towards at the moment

```sql
-- Add page level compression
alter table     dbo.TableName
rebuild with    (data_compression = page)
; 
go

-- Add primary key
alter table             dbo.TableName
add constraint          PK_TableName
primary key clustered   (<Columns>)
;
go

-- Add NC_IXs here
...
...
```

<strike>Ive looked [here (PK creation documentation)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189039(v=sql.100).aspx) and [here (ALTER TABLE documentation)](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273(v=sql.100).aspx), but can't see anything definitive about whether or not any indexes inherit table compression settings.</strike> [The answer to this particular question is "No, compression is not inherited", found here on dba.stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/28034/7226)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The clustered index is in fact the table.  On the assumption that your primary key is clustered then I would create a clustered primary key with page level compression rather than trying to do it in two steps.

```
-- Add primary key
ALTER TABLE             dbo.TableName
ADD CONSTRAINT          PK_TableName
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED   (<Columns>)
WITH (DATA_COMPRESSION = PAGE)
;
```

I would also copy about 100k rows to a temporary (temporary physical not #temporary) table and run some tests.  Try running compression first, clustered key first, try doing them as one step.  See what runs fastest.  I would guess it will be one step personally :).

Answer (score 2):

Either way, page compression is going to shuffle data around a LOT.  I would estimate doing the compression first would result in less overall I/O since the clustering operation will be reading compressed pages.